# Console error because store variable used in template only gets populated after async API call

Tags: vue.js, vuex

In my component I display many properties (only showing two below) of my `selectedPlan` store variable after getting its value from the store:

```
<div>
  {{ selectedPlan.periodTitle }}
</div>
<div>
 {{ selectedPlan.currency }}
</div>

...mapGetters(['selectedPlan', 'whatever'])
```

Problem: this variable is `null` by default and only gets populated after some unrelated component makes an API call.

The variable does get displayed so no problem on screen. But in console I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'periodTitle' of null

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `selectedPlan` may not be available(or has `null` value) on the first render, you are facing that error. You have one of three ways to solve this issue:

1. Add a loader and wait until `selectedPlan` is available (best way in my opinion from the UX perspective)
2. Add a null check before accessing values like:

```
{{ (selectedPlan || {}).periodTitle }}
```

Or much better, use a computed property:

```
computed: {
  safeSelectedPlan: () => {
    return this.selectedPlan || {}
  }
}
```

and then use `safeSelectedPlan` in your template.

3. Use a library like `lodash` to `get` the values for variables safely.
   Here is the documentation link to lodash: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15